# Unable to disable jsp cache

Tags: jsp, browser-cache

I don't want the browser to cache a specified jsp, so I used the code below in my jsp:

```
<%
    response.setHeader("Pragma", "No-cache");
    response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
    response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0);
%>
```

However, it doesn't work. Everytime I press the back button, the browser shows the cached page without refreshing.

Does the position of the code in the jsp matter? How to disable the cache?

Comment: don't edit out the error that prompted the question...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A typo? `Pramga` instead of Pragma? Try.

```
<%        
    response.setHeader("Pragma", "No-cache");
    response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
    response.setDateHeader("Expires", -1);
%>
```

EDIT: see this question [How to control web page caching, across all browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49547/making-sure-a-web-page-is-not-cached-across-all-browsers)

Comment: OK, I corrected that but found no use. Maybe it's browser matter?

Comment: I updated the answer, please try now. I got it from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/49547/making-sure-a-web-page-is-not-cached-across-all-browsers)

Comment: This time it works, thanx! I don't even to set the browser anymore.

Comment: This accepted answer is dedicated to @BalusC. I see his answer everywhere for this type of question on SO.